# Freeswitch: Store variable in XML CDR from Dial Strings

Tags: variables, lua, freeswitch

I am using a lua script in Freeswitch.

The routes are generated from SQL queries. And there may be several trunks output.

For that I use bridge failover:

```
bridge({ignore_early_media=false}[nobal_amt=-250,execute_on_post_originate=limit hash outbound NameTrunk 500 !NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE,gateway=4]sofia/gateway/NameTrunk/xxxxxxxxxxxxx|[nobal_amt=-250,execute_on_post_originate=limit hash outbound NameTrunk2 500 !NORMAL_TEMPORARY_FAILURE,gateway=5]sofia/gateway/NameTrunk2/xxxxxxxxxxxxx)
```

The problem are the channels variable in dial strings, these are not stored in the XML CDR and do not know the variable "gateway" (gateway=4 or gateway=5). It is very important that I can save channels variables that are in dial strings.

Comment: try enclose `execute_on_post_originate` argument in single quotes

Comment: Nothing...

I'm testing with another Freeswitch system that I use to send Fax. Sending faxes with "api originate" and if it works. But with a bridge does not work.